# Why my action.GET_CONTENT is not working, but action.PICK works?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I made a `FileChooser` activity that implemented `action.GET_CONTENT` and `action.PICK` intent filters in the Manifest (see below full code). Yet, I cannot make `action.GET_CONTENT` to work with audio files, although `action.PICK` does work.

More precisely, if from another app (a Music Player I made) I try:

```
Intent fc = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
fc.setType("audio/*");                     // also works with "vnd.android.cursor.dir/audio"
fc.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(fc, 1);
```

my filemanager is called. It also works if I do:

```
Intent fc = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
fc.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(fc, 1);
```

But it does **NOT** work if I try:

```
Intent fc = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
fc.setType("audio/*");
fc.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(fc, 1);
```

This is my Manifest file, with several intentfilters to try to see if some of them works:

```
 ....
    <activity
        android:name=".FileChooser"
        android:label="File Chooser"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/audio"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` on modern versions of Android is handled purely by the OS, AFAIK. If you have access to some unique content, you could implement a `DocumentsProvider` to have that be available to all apps using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh... So I cannot use my FileChooser to choose attachments for, say, K9 email client? K9 uses `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to pick attachments.

Comment: AFAIK, that is correct. I am surprised that your chooser gets started for the no-MIME-type case, but that might just be a hole in Google's implementation.

Comment: I see... What a pity! Thanks anyway.